# Edit what displays in an iframe

Tags: iframe, editing

I'm trying to display content from anther site on to mine using an iframe. I'm just wondering if its possible to only display certain parts (divs) of this external page in the iframe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and use some [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) on your site to dynamically alter the styles of the external site.  I did something similar with SSRS where we had an iframe containing SSRS reports which we wanted to style.  We used jQuery in the master page to find the matching elements inside the frame target and alter them as required.

As long as the external site is well marked up (plenty of ids, good semantic structure) you may be able to hide/re-arrange elements as you require.  You may also need to delay the jQuery execution as the frame contents may not be completely loaded by the time your JavaScript executes.

You can find a VERY simple example [here](http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/).

BUT, be careful of the legalities involved with showing partial content from someone else's site.  If you're presenting their site as your own or without identifying information, you could be infringing on their copyright.